# Dynamically cast Number class to one of its child

Tags: java, casting

How i can dynamically (value passed dynamically) Number class to according child type like Integer, Double, Float, Long, Short, or Byte?

For example, i have:

```
while (source.hasNext()) {
    Number next = (Number) source.next();
    Command command = new CommandFactory().defineCommand(next);
    ??? value = command.execute(next); // value can be Integer, Double, Long or another
    if (value > 10) {
        System.out.println("value is more than 10);
    }
}
```

`Command` is an interface that have execute method like in command pattern. When i call execute of the class IntCommand, DoubleCommand, FloatCommand, LongCommand, ShortCommandm or ByteCommand it converts number to according value and returns according type like one of them (they are all the same):

```
public class IntCommand implements Command {
    @Override
    public Integer execute(Number number) {
        return number.intValue();
    }
}
```

The problem is that i need to compare this casted number to another number (like 10) but it's impossible as Number has no overloading of arithmetic operations.

What is the best way to provide universal casting?

Comment: You could use `value.doubleValue() > 10` that will work for Float, Integer, Double and Long, but could not for BigDecimal / BigInteger

Comment: Checking the BigDeciman / BigInteger API this should work fine also in these cases, since the conversion in the worst case (positive number exceeding Double range) will return a Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY that can be compared with your threshold.

Comment: Trying to be generic over numbers is generally not a good idea.  Pick one type -- `BigDecimal`, if you have to be maximally generic -- and stick to it.